# Convert COUNTIFS formula to SUM(IF) to enable external workbook references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I need to convert the following formula to one that uses `SUM(IF)`, as I am given a `#value` error when the external data source is closed.

```
=COUNTIFS(test1.xlsx!$B:$B,"Group1",
    test1.xlsx!$C:$C,$D13,
    test1.xlsx!$AB:$AB,">="&F12,
    test1.xlsx!$AB:$AB,"<"&DATE(YEAR(F12),
    MONTH(F12)+1,1))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to return the desired value even when the data source is closed? Or do you just want to return say "Unknown" when the data source is closed?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm trying to return the desired value when the workbook is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you think SUM(IF) would make the situation any better. You need a worksheet name in your external links. So where I may have:

```
='E:\Temp\Stack Overflow\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$I$9
```

You are missing the reference to Sheet1 (or whatever worksheet you want to link to). Also, if 'Test1.xlsx' is not in the same folder as the current spreadsheet, you will need to include the path to the file (as in my example).